# Is actionscript a client-side or server-side language?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Someone just told me that Actionscript is a client-side language. I'm not sure how this is true if we save the .as files on the server? I also heard several times before people referring to it as a server-side language. Which is true (if you can, please clarify with a reference). Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please read:

[Client-Side (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side)

[Server-Side (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side)

Executable files are ALWAYS stored in the server. What matters is where they will be run.

In your case, please note that .as files are **not** executable, they will be compiled into a .swf flash movie which will be run by the flash player inside the client's browser.

Comment: also, note that you don't need to upload .as files ;)

Answer (score 2):

It runs on the client, that's why it is client side code.

Answer (score 1):

Its a client-side language.  Even if the files are saved as discrete items in the web site they aren't executed on the server, they are downloaded and executed on the client.

Answer (score 0):

There are many systems that run server-side AS. FMS, SmartFoxServer...

Answer (score 0):

While most action script is client side, as Joel noted there are server side implementations.  Additionally, Adobe demoed an implementation that runs actionscript on both sides without forcing the developer to discriminate at Adobe MAX 2008.  You can watch [that video here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uImhKFhwAu0), or read a [synopsis of it here](http://www.joeflash.ca/blog/2008/11/61.html).